# PATH variable not working properly with hg

Tags: bash, path, mercurial

I am having a `CentOS` remote machine where I have `hg` installed. It was working fine for long time and today when I am trying to use `hg`  commands, I got the following errors,

```
[dinesh@lab test]$ hg st
-bash: hg: command not found
[dinesh@lab test]$
```

Then I realized that it might be missed from `PATH`. (But, how?, not sure.). I checked the `which hg` command and it failed to give me the path.

`hg` is located at `/usr/local/bin/hg` and using the whole path for `hg`, made it work. I tried adding the `hg` path to `PATH` variable like,

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/hg
```

which also didn't work. Then I have created an alias for `hg` command as,

```
alias hg="/usr/local/bin/hg"
```

which at least made it work.

But, eventually, I end up with the same issue for `kdiff3` (which is also working fine till yesterday). Tried the above and only alias made it work. (again)

Now, I am in need of using `hg kdiff3` command and for which I am keep on getting

```
/bin/sh: kdiff3: command not found
```

But, I have the `kdiff3` extension enabled in the `hgrc` file for the repository. (which is again working till yesterday)  :(

```
[dinesh@lab test]$ cat .hg/hgrc
[paths]
default = ssh://remoteuser@xxx.xx.xx.xxx//repo/code

[ui]
username= dinesh <dinesh.sivaji@domain.com>

[extensions]
mq =
fetch =
purge =
hgext.extdiff =
hgext.acl =

[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 =

[dinesh@lab test]$
```

**Note :** After making changes in the `.profile` file for `PATH` or `alias`, I am sourcing them each time, for changes to take effect.

Can anyone suggest what can I do to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$PATH` contains *directories*, not files, therefore it should list `/usr/local/bin` instead.

*(Think about it: right now it has just `/bin:/usr/bin`, not `/bin/ls:/bin/cp:/usr/bin/ssh`...)*